# Why isn't string.Replace working as I expected?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am writing c# code to replace certain words from a file. The 2 line demo simple code that I have written is not working. There is no error and `Console.WriteLine` is also giving correct output.

```
string strFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\TCS\stop_words.txt");
Console.WriteLine("strfilecontent" + strFileContent);
strFileContent = strFileContent.Replace("actually" , " ");
```

The string "actually" is not getting replaced in the file.
What can be the problem here?

Comment: What's the problem here? This code will print the string before the replace, and doesn't look to save the string back to the file.

Comment: Do you mean the variable strFileContent  is not changed after the replace call because in your example you don't use it again?

Comment: You need to send you 'strFileContent' string back out the file, the contenct is being replaced in memory but not back out to the file.

Comment: It might be an idea to see the content of the file you're reading from too...

Answer (score 10):

Ofcourse it's not getting replaced in the file, as you only *read* the data and then alter it.

You`ll have to write it back to the file if want to apply the changes.

```
string strFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\TCS\stop_words.txt");
Console.WriteLine("strfilecontent" + strFileContent);
strFileContent = strFileContent.Replace("actually" , " ");

StreamWriter SW = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\TCS\stop_words.txt");
SW.Write(strFileContent);
SW.Close();
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a string with the replaced value, but you are never writing that value back to the file. Therefore, the file remains unchanged.

To fix, add the following line to write the changed value back to the file:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\toshal\Documents\TCS\stop_words.txt";
string strFileContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
Console.WriteLine("strfilecontent" + strFileContent);
strFileContent = strFileContent.Replace("actually" , " ");
File.WriteAllText(path, strFileContent);
```